# Android Studio from database with sqlite to GridView and header columns

Tags: android, sqlite, datagridview

I have a table in my db:

```
piecetable (description, imgdescription, imgpiece,  codsag, codoe, n, csct, a, b, cod_auto, cod_brand)
```

I have a simple GridView with eight fixed columns called piecedatagridview
and I want get data from db and put into this GridView.
How can i do that?

Two columns must contain two images got from imgdescription and imgpiece, found into the `drawable` folder.

How can I load, at first, header column in bold character into the GridView and then load the rows from the db?

Code:

```
<GridLayout
            android:layout_width="1172dp"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <GridView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="263dp"
                android:id="@+id/tabellaPezzi"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:numColumns="8"
                android:smoothScrollbar="false" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add Java **code**, not just the xml **layout**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question with another question: what do you need a GridList for? A GridList is used when representing same element types into a grid-like layout; in your case, a ListView wrapping up all the items you need to show seems the better options.
For the drawables part, save into your DB the resource int addresses of res/drawable folder (i.e. R.drawable.drawable_name), and then fetch the actual images when building your row.

Comment: Ok. I need to show data as a normal DatagridView made in C#. Or it would be needed ListView?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite familiar with C#, but I assume you want to show a different object in every column of a row, right? In that case, ListView is what you need!